# Spring AOP xml configuration doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, spring, namespaces, aop

I tried to write a simple AOP program and I configure the xml file like below. But when I ran the program, the result seems not calling the advice but only execute non-advice part.

Here is the method class:

```
public class MessageWriterStdOut {
    public void writeMessage() {
        System.out.print("World");
    }
}
```

This is the bean class:

```
public class MyBeanOfHelloWorld {
  private MessageWriterStdOut messageWriterStdOut;
    public void execute() {
        messageWriterStdOut.writeMessage();
    }
    public void setMessageWriterStdOut(MessageWriterStdOut messageWriterStdOut) {
        this.messageWriterStdOut = messageWriterStdOut;
    }
}
```

The advice class is like this:

```
public class MessageDecorator implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.print("Hello ");
        Object retVal = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println("!");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

The main method is :

```
public class HelloWorldAopExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("/META-INF/spring/context-aop.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        MyBeanOfHelloWorld myBeanOfHelloWorld = (MyBeanOfHelloWorld) ctx.getBean("myBeanOfHelloWorld");
        myBeanOfHelloWorld.execute();
    }
}
```

and the xml configuration is :

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="helloExecution"
            expression="execution(* com..playground..writeMessage*()) and args(invocation)" />
        <aop:aspect ref="advice">
            <aop:around pointcut-ref="helloExecution" method="invoke" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
    <bean id="advice" class="com..playground.aophelloworld.MessageDecorator" />
    <bean id="messageWriterStdOut"
        class="com..playground.aophelloworld.MessageWriterStdOut" />
    <bean id="myBeanOfHelloWorld" class="com..playground.aophelloworld.MyBeanOfHelloWorld">
        <property name="messageWriterStdOut" ref="messageWriterStdOut" />
    </bean>
```

But the result is still only "world", while the expected result is "hello world!"

Comment: what `args(invocation)` is supposed to do?

Comment: Because when I didn't add this args it always show error: "Pointcut is malformed: error at ::0 formal unbound in ". So I add this args which is the arg of the method in the advice class. (actually it doesn't need based on the tutorial..)

Answer (score 0):

In the xml configuration, why some of your package paths are having two dots? For example:

```
<aop:pointcut id="helloExecution"
        expression="execution(* com..playground..writeMessage*()) and args(invocation)" />
```

should be:

```
<aop:pointcut id="helloExecution"
        expression="execution(* com.playground.writeMessage*()) and args(invocation)" />
```

and some other places:

```
<bean id="advice" class="com.playground.aophelloworld.MessageDecorator" />
<bean id="myBeanOfHelloWorld" class="com.playground.aophelloworld.MyBeanOfHelloWorld">
    <property name="messageWriterStdOut" ref="messageWriterStdOut" />
```

Updated:
Can you try this:

```
<aop:pointcut id="helloExecution"
        expression="execution(* com..playground.MessageWriterStdOut.writeMessage(..))" />
```

Comment: I delete some part of the class path because it's a lit bit long to show, so I use ".." here just for short. But here "playground..writeMessage*()" is because I saw it on tutorial setting like this and when I delete one of the dots it shows syntax error.

Comment: Seems like if I delete "args(invocation)" it will always show error info like "Pointcut is malformed: error at ::0 formal unbound in".